# Populating data in GridView in a peculiar manner [Special Case]

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, gridview

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/837/6uvs.jpg/

I have the following tables and relationships.

When loading the NEW_CHALLAN form, I am trying to fill a Grid View with Product Details - Product Name, Stage, Pro, Katta, Packing, Rate, Quantity.

I am facing a problem (getting 0 records as result set) when using JOIN for this operation as there are no matching records(ChallanId, ProductId, OrderId) in the ChallanProductDetails table yet (when loading the form)

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you try to solve this problem by self?

Comment: You need to answer the following: winforms or asp.net? Provide datasource and query. Decribe how the controls are wired up.

Comment: Are you trying to load Product Details even if there is nothing in ChallanProductDetails?  If so, then try a left join in your query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load product details even tough there are no order/challan details then you can try something like below,

select a.productname,a.productprice,c.stage,c.pro...etc from product a
left outer join challanproductdetails b
on a.productid= b.productid

Comment: SELECT Product.ProductName AS [Product Name], ChallanProductDetails.Stage, ChallanProductDetails.Pro AS [Producer], ChallanProductDetails.LotNo AS [Lot No], ChallanProductDetails.Katta, ChallanProductDetails.Packing, ChallanProductDetails.RatePerKg AS [Rate Per Kg], ChallanProductDetails.Quantity AS [Quantity in Kgs]

FROM (ChallanProductDetails LEFT JOIN OrderProductDetails ON ChallanProductDetails.OrderId=OrderProductDetails.OrderId) 

LEFT JOIN Product ON OrderProductDetails.ProductId=Product.ProductId

WHERE (((ChallanProductDetails.OrderID)=3));

Comment: I am getting 0 rows when I fire this query

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. I would like to repeat that there are is no matching record (here, OrderId) in the ChallanProductDetails yet.

Answer (score 0):

brother I am not sure what exactly your asking for is it to retrieve data from a view or two tables if you are retrieving only then why don't you create a view of two tables and just call it straight to the grid that will be easy.

Please correct me if I am wrong.